# Installting psycopg2 package for python 3.5 on unix

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2, setup.py

I am trying to install package psycopg2 to connect with postgres database but getting below error on running this command

*python3.5 /usr/local/bin/psycopg2-2.7.3.2/setup.py install*

*running build_ext
building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/psycopg
gcc*** command here
In file included from psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:27:
./psycopg/psycopg.h:30:2: error: #error "Psycopg requires PostgreSQL client library (libpq) >= 9.1"*

Current environment already have python 2.4, we installed another version 3.5.  Now both versions are present.

Since there no direct connectivity with external net, I got the file for psycopg2 package and installing using setup.py

Please suggest, what I am missing here and how can I resolve this.
Note that cannot connect to internet as this is a close environment so cannot use PIP for installation of package. My main aim is to connect to postgres database.

Answer (score 2):

The key here is

> Psycopg requires PostgreSQL client library (libpq) >= 9.1

Make sure that the first `pg_config` on your `PATH` is from PostgreSQL version 9.1 or higher.

From [the documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#prerequisites):

> Psycopg is a C wrapper around the libpq PostgreSQL client library. To install it from sources you will need:
>
> - The **pg_config** program: it is usually installed by the **libpq-dev** package but sometimes it is not in a PATH directory. Having it in the PATH greatly streamlines the installation, so try running `pg_config --version`

Comment: Thanks for info @Laurenz. I checked that. At the same pre-requisite from documentation, it says  
The current psycopg2 implementation supports:  
  
- Python 2 versions from 2.6 to 2.7  
- Python 3 versions from 3.2 to 3.6  
- PostgreSQL server versions from 7.4 to 10  
- PostgreSQL client library version from 9.1  
  
So I think it should work with postgres 8.1 as well

Comment: No, it won't. 8.1 < 9.1. You need a later client version. What's the idea of using a prehistoric version like that? You're playing with the life of your data.